# How to Assign TextInput(Factory object) value to variable

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I've been trying to assign the text input to a variable
my TextInput object is inside a factory object (object_1)

I've tried to Assign it using

```
txt_1=self.root.ids.txt.text
```

but it dosent work

Here is the whole code

```
from kivymd.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.factory import Factory 

kv='''
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

# this is object 1 which will be added to main grid

<object_1@BoxLayout>:

    orientation:'vertical'
    size_hint_y:None
    adaptive_height: True
    height:self.minimum_height 
    id:obj_1

    TextInput:
        size_hint:None,None 
        id:txt



#main grid

BoxLayout:
    orientation:'vertical'
    size_hint_y:None
    adaptive_height: True
    height:self.minimum_height 

    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        size_hint_y:None 
        adaptive_height:True
        height:self.minimum_height 
        id:sc_grid          
        Button:
            size_hint:None,None 
            text: 'Add 1'
            on_press:
                app.add_1()          
                    
        Button:
            size_hint:None,None 
            text: 'Assign value'
            on_press:
                app.Assign()                
                
'''

class MyApp(App):
    
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

    
    def add_1(self):
        self.root.ids.sc_grid.add_widget(Factory.object_1())

    # this crashes

    def Assign(self):
        txt_1=self.root.ids.txt.text
        
MyApp().run()
```

In the above code object_1 in added to main grid when button is pressed

On press TextInput object appears in main grid

After entering the value,i want to click the assign button to assign value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out an alternative solution to solve this by assigning it though the kv,
Here is the code

```
from kivymd.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.factory import Factory 

kv='''
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

# this is object 1 which will be added to main grid

<object_1@BoxLayout>:

    orientation:'vertical'
    size_hint_y:None
    adaptive_height: True
    height:self.minimum_height 
    id:obj_1

    TextInput:
        size_hint:None,None 
        id:txt
                        
    Button:
        size_hint:None,None 
        text: 'Assign value'
        on_press:
            txt_1=root.ids.txt.text

#main grid

Screen:
    id:scrn
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        size_hint_y:None
        adaptive_height: True
        height:self.minimum_height 

        GridLayout:
            cols:1
            size_hint_y:None 
            adaptive_height:True
            height:self.minimum_height 
            id:sc_grid          
            Button:
                size_hint:None,None 
                text: 'Add 1'
                on_press:
                    app.add_1()          

'''

class MyApp(App):
    
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

    
    def add_1(self):
        self.root.ids.sc_grid.add_widget(Factory.object_1())

MyApp().run()
```

But i still hope someone has a solution to do this via the App class

Answer (score 0):

your code  should be like:

```
TextInput:
        size_hint:None,None 
        id:txt
        text:""
```

You forgot to add `text` variable.

Comment: There aren't any mistakes with the ids , my TextInput id is ' txt '  , you might've mistaken seeing txt_1=self.root.ids.txt.text

Comment: you can find more about '.text' here https://kivy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api-kivy.core.text.text_layout.html?highlight=.text